# What does Preserving mean of Android GC?

Tags: java, android, jvm

I find a table which shows features of different kinds of GC in Android OS.
I want to know what the Preserving in the table mean. 
The table is below:

**GC_FOR_[M]ALLOC**

Partial:Y Concurrent:N Preserving:Y

When is triggered: Not enough space for an "ordinary" Object to be allocated.

**GC_CONCURRENT**

Partial:Y Concurrent:Y Preserving:Y

When is triggered: Automatic GC triggered by exceeding a heap occupancy threshold.

**GC_EXPLICT**

Partial:N Concurrent:Y Preserving:Y

When is triggered: Explicit GC via Runtime.gc(), VMRuntime.gc(), or SIGUSR1

**GC_BEFORE_OOM**

Partial:N Concurrent:N  Preserving:N

When is triggered: Final attempt to reclaim memory before throwing an OOM.

The table come from this Web Site : http://www.kandroid.org/board/data/board/conference/file_in_body/1/511th_kandroidconf_memory_and_performance.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's an asterisk next to the "preserving" heading, and the corresponding note below the table says

> Preserving softly reachable objects or not

referring to whether SoftReferences are cleared or not.  Java VMs attempt to keep the objects referred to by SoftReferences in memory, but if the garbage collector needs the space for other objects, it may collect them (if they aren't strongly reachable, of course).  For more information on SoftReferences, read the [soft-references] tag wiki or try a search for `[java][soft-references]`.

In this case, the first three collection types are "normal" and the JVM will not clear SoftReferences.  The last case is a last-ditch attempt to reclaim memory to avoid throwing OutOfMemoryError, and the JVM will clear SoftReferences so it can collect more objects.  (SoftReferences are *required* to be cleared before throwing OOME by the specification.)  Note that SoftReference policy varies by JVM and GC algorithm, so other VMs might clear "old" SoftReferences (for some meaning of "old") during normal collections.